# How to modify the attribute of super class using subclass in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, subclass

I have a class Rectangle

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
    def set_width(self, width):
        self.width = width
        
    def set_height(self, height):
        self.height = height
        
    def get_area(self):
        return self.width * self.height
    
    def get_perimeter(self):
        return self.width*2 + self.height*2
    
    def get_diagonal(self):
        return (self.width ** 2 + self.height ** 2) ** .5
    
    def get_picture(self):
        picture = str()
        if self.width >= 50 | self.height >= 50:
            return "Too big for picture."
        
        for height in range(self.height):
            picture += "*"*self.width+"\n"
            
        return picture
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Rectangle(width={self.width}, height={self.height})"
```

And a subclass of it Square

```
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length, length)
        self.length = length
    
    def set_side(self, length):
        super().__init__(length, length)
        self.length = length
    
    def set_width(self, length):
        super().__init__(length, length)
        self.length = length        
        
    def set_height(self, length):
        super().__init__(length, length)
        self.length = length
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Square(side={self.length})"
```

Here I called the super().**init**() every time I want to change values.

What I want is instead of defining set_height and set_width explicitly in Square class too, is there a way I can set both height and width to length by calling set side and the str repr should also show the new set side?
Also, I feel like there is a better way to do this then what I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Rectangle:
        def __init__(self, width, height):
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            
        def set_width(self, width):
            self.width = width
            
        def set_height(self, height):
            self.height = height
            
        def get_area(self):
            return self.width * self.height
        
        def get_perimeter(self):
            return self.width*2 + self.height*2
        
        def get_diagonal(self):
            return (self.width ** 2 + self.height ** 2) ** .5
        
        def get_picture(self):
            picture = str()
            if self.width >= 50 | self.height >= 50:
                return "Too big for picture."
            
            for height in range(self.height):
                picture += "*"*self.width+"\n"
                
            return picture
        
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"Rectangle(width={self.width}, height={self.height})"
    
    
    
    class Square(Rectangle):
        def __init__(self, length):
            super().__init__(length, length)
            self.length = length
        
        def set_side(self, length):
            super().__init__(length, length)
            self.length = length
        
        def set_width(self, length):
            # super().__init__(length, length)
            # self.length = length     
            self.set_side(length)   
            
        def set_height(self, length):
            # super().__init__(length, length)
            # self.length = length
            self.set_side(length)   
    
            
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"Square(side={self.length})"
    
    
    
    # r = Rectangle(20, 20)
    s = Square(20)
    
    # print(r)
    print(s)
    s.set_width(60)
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar example:

```
class Rectangle : 

   def __init__(self,length,width):
        self.length = length 
        self.width = width  
       

class Square(Rectangle) : 
    
   def __init__(self, length, width):
       super().__init__(length, width)  

   def area(self): 
       return self.length*self.width 


class Cube(Rectangle): 

   def __init__(self,length, width,height):
       super().__init__(length, width)  
       self.height = height  
       
   def volume(self): 
       return self.length*self.width*self.height

square = Square(3,3) 
cube  = Cube(3,3,3) 

print(square.area()) 
print(cube.volume())
```